# Find if value already exists in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm adding a row with new member details. The following code works

```
With Worksheets("Enroll Course")
 'insert blank row 8 in Course sheet and copy details to it
      Worksheets(.Range("C6").Value).Rows(8).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
     .Range("C5").Copy Worksheets(.Range("C6").Value).Range("A8") 'member name
End With
```

The member name is here .Range("C5").

The worksheet is here Worksheets(.Range("C6").Value)

If the member already exists on worksheet, then instead of the insert and paste to A8, I want to find which row they are on and paste details to that row in column B, rather than to row 8
How do I find if member already on the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with the code below, but there may be simpler ways.

If I understand the question correctly, when the member name already exists you want to post data to column B of the row with the member name.

```
Dim AnsRng As Range
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set Sheet = Worksheets("Enroll Course")

'Use autofilter to check if the member name is already in target worksheet
Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value).AutoFilterMode = False
'A2:B8 here is an example range that you want to search. 
'Assumes column to be searched for existing member name is column A.
Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value).Range("A2:B8").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
Criteria1:=Worksheets("Enroll").Range("C4").Value
Set AnsRng = Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value). _
UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'If name already exists, add content to column B
If AnsRng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    'Find the row where the member name exists
    LastRow = Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value).Cells. _
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    'Paste data "Enroll Course" C6 into column B of selected row
    Sheet.Range("C6").Copy Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value). _
    Range("B" & (LastRow))
    Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value).AutoFilterMode = False
Else
'If name does not exist
    With Worksheets("Enroll")
   'insert blank row 8 in Course sheet and copy details to it
        Worksheets(.Range("C6").Value).Rows(8).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        'Insert member name
        .Range("C5").Copy Worksheets(.Range("C6").Value).Range("A3")
        Worksheets(Sheet.Range("C6").Value).AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End If
```

Comment: This worked, thanks Ben. I had to change the range to start at row 7 and change to Count > 7, instead of 1.

Comment: This has stopped working. When I use debug I can see that the filter works correctly and the name already exists but the value of AnsRng is blank. Any ideas why?